# LOGIN FORM using class

Tags: c#, string, forms, class, events

I have button1_click in Form1.. and i want string usernamebox.text and passwordbox.text to login class i created it before.. and I got stuck here.. Login class work but button code not how Get textBox value in from1 to login class

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String c1 = new String();
        c1 = UsernameBox.Text;
        Login.Validation_user(c1.ToString());

        String c2 = new String();
        c2 = PasswordBox.Text;
        Login.Validation_pass(c2.ToString());
        
    }
```

this my string

```
static string connectionClient = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sample2"].ConnectionString;

    private static bool Validation { get; set; }
```

this my login class "Password"

```
public static void Validation_pass (string password)
    {
        if (!Validation)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionClient))
            {
                string checkForLogQuery = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Password=@pass";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(checkForLogQuery, sqlConn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
                sqlConn.Open();
                int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("wellcome");
                    Form9 f9 = new Form9();
                    f9.Close();
                    f9.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
                    Form10 f10 = new Form10();
                    f10.Show();
                    Validation = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Key was incorrect");
                    Validation = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

and "username" it same what is above

Comment: You need one method which validates both at once

Comment: @ADyson How am I new to C# ? Can you write the **code**?

Comment: It's just a method which accepts two parameters instead of one. It would help us a lot if you show what your existing login class is doing.

Comment: @ADyson this is my Login class [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/qNG8UH14)

Comment: Paste the relevant parts of it here please. Your question should directly contain everything needed to solve it without relying on other links. Otherwise the moderators can mark it as off-topic.

Comment: Anyway basically you're aiming to be able to write a query like `SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Username =@user and Password = @pass` - so that you can check that there's a single user which matches both the username and the password

Comment: P.s. storing passwords in plain text is a security risk. They should be hashed really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate both `password` and `username` together

Here is an example

```js
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var res = Login.Validate(PasswordBox.Text, UsernameBox.Text);

  if (res)
    MessageBox.Show("wellcome");
  else
    MessageBox.Show("UserName or Password dose not match.");
}



public static bool Validate(string password, string userName) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
    return false;

  using(MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionClient)) {
    string checkForLogQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM Login WHERE Password=@pass and LOWER(UserName) = LOWER(@userName)";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(checkForLogQuery, sqlConn);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
    sqlConn.Open();
    var value = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    sqlConn.Close();
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This was good but I have a problem with button1_click in Form1 Code

Comment: can you help me here

Comment: Im really not understanding the problem, I have simplify and updated my answer based on your code ,please check and let me know

Comment: Thank you Alena it works now.. but I delete code "cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure".. To work.. Thanks again